# How to run python playwright in Azure functions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, playwright, playwright-python

Playwright worksf on my machine when I run it through the normal Python interpreter, but when I try to deploy it as an Azure function I get errors.

I'm trying to follow instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949978/running-playwright-in-azure-function) but I'm getting `"webkit" browser was not found. Please complete Playwright installation via running "python -m playwright install"` which I think is an error that can't occur if you're using npm.

I've tried creating an azure devops Pipeline which has this step:

```
    - bash: |
        python -m venv worker_venv
        source worker_venv/bin/activate
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        python -m playwright install
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
```

I've also tried just doing it from my code:

```
os.system('python -m playwright install')
```

I can see that the `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH` environment variable is set to `0`.

How can I get this to run on Azure functions?

Comment: How do you deploy to azure function? Please share some key steps.  If you deploy to Azure function locally (e.g. VS Code), will it work?   On the other hand, is this issue specific to azure devops, or does it have the same issue with other deployment methods?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT yes, it works locally. It doesn't work with VSCode deploy or devops.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got this working (adapted from [this repo](https://github.com/anthonychu/20220303-python-func-playwright)):

- Include `playwright` in your `requirements.txt`
- Use the default remote build when deploying
- Add these settings to your function in Azure:

  - `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH` = `/home/site/wwwroot`
  - `POST_BUILD_COMMAND` = `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(find /tmp/oryx/platforms/python -regex '.*/bin/python[0-9.]+$' -type f | sort -V | tail -n 1) && echo $PYTHON_EXECUTABLE && export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted/.python_packages/lib/site-packages && $PYTHON_EXECUTABLE -m playwright install`

You can customize what gets installed in that last step of the command, i.e. `$PYTHON_EXECUTABLE -m playwright install chrome`

Comment: Did you get this working when deploying using a Devops Pipeline?

Comment: No, I'm deploying manually, but I'd expect it to work whenever you're deploying with `func azure functionapp publish $function`

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the code works locally and it doesn't work when you deploy it to azure function. It seems you haven't add the modules which you installed into `requirements.txt`. When you deploy it to azure function, azure cloud will install the modules according to `requirement.txt`. So just add a line like `playwright==0.162.1` in your `requirements.txt`.